# how to trigger a button in HTML using python?

Tags: python, html, button

I want to trigger a button of a html file.

There is a web site in which there are number of options and a button.
After clicking on the button, using the options, a html table is created on next page.

I want to automate the process but I dont know how I can trigger a button using python.
DO anyone knows about the same?

Comment: Python doesn't run in web-browsers, you'd need to use javascript.

Comment: @tony : yes but then is there any way with which I can trigger the button and fetch the data from next page?

Comment: Sam, I think you'll need to be more specific if you want a decent answer. It's very difficult to tell what you want to do. Perhaps you could post your existing code and detail what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can use windmill, mechanize or selenium RC.